# I need to read data from xml by selecting lang

Tags: php, xml

I need to read data from xml by selecting lang "FR"

```
$sxml = '<product>
<description>
<long_desc xml:lang="EN">English
</long_desc>
<long_desc xml:lang="FR">French
</long_desc>
<long_desc xml:lang="IT">Italy
</long_desc>
<description>
</product>';

$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $sxml->long_desc[0]->attributes('xml', TRUE)->lang;
```

this example shows "EN"

I need to pull out "French" with "FR"
I have no idea

Comment: `$sxml->long_desc[1]->attributes('xml', TRUE)->lang;` will produce FR and `$sxml->long_desc[2]->attributes('xml', TRUE)->lang;` will produce IT. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: no, I need to read "French" by entering "FR" or "English" by entering "EN" or "IT" by entering "Italy" sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search your xml by attribute, you can use [`xpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$sxml = '<product>
<description>
<long_desc xml:lang="EN">English
</long_desc>
<long_desc xml:lang="FR">French
</long_desc>
<long_desc xml:lang="IT">Italy
</long_desc>
</description>
</product>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($sxml);

var_dump($xml->xpath('/product/description/long_desc[@xml:lang="FR"]'));
```

To get the string value you are looking for:

```
var_dump((string) $xml->xpath('/product/description/long_desc[@xml:lang="FR"]')[0]);
```

You can replace the `"FR"` at the en with `"IT"`, etc.

Note that I have corrected your invalid xml to make this work.